# Can Hangfire Job be exposed as Service?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

Is there any way to expose Hangfire Job as Service? I wanted some of my hangfire jobs to be triggered  from outside of hangfire project.

Answer (score 0):

After some analysis we are able to achieve this. since it will be useful to someone i am sharing here.

1. I am using .netcore razor pages in hangfire project.
2. Create normal web api controller inside hangfire project. (.addmvc() function should be there in startup)
3. Add endpoint inside api.

   ```
   [HttpGet("RecurringJob")]
    public void TriggerRecurringJob(string jobId)
    {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IJobScheduler>(
                            JobId,
                            task => task.ScheduleAnyJob(),
                            "jobCron",
                            timeZone: TimeZone.Local);

         RecurringJob.Trigger(jobId);
    }
   ```
4. Now you can run expose and consume as normal api inside hangfire project itself. If you require any authentication then you can implement filters.